# Why does a big unreferenced HashMap increase performance in Java?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, hashmap

I have a performance problem that I can't get my head around. I am writing a Java application that parses huge (> 20 million lines) text files and stores certain information in a Set.
I measure the performance in seconds per million lines. Since I need a lot of memory, I usually run the program with -Xmx6000m and -Xms4000m.

If I just run the program, It parses 1 Million lines in about 6 seconds. However, I realized after some performance investigations, that if I add this code before the actual parsing routine, performance increases to under 3 seconds per 1 million lines:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("graphs.nt"));
HashMap<String, String> foo = new HashMap<String, String>();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    foo.put(line, "foo");
}
foo = null;
br.close();
br = null;
```

The graphs.nt file is about 9 million lines long. The performance increase persists even if I do not set foo to null, this is mainly to demonstrate that the map is in fact not used by the program.

The rest of the code is completely unrelated. I use a parser from openrdf sesame to read a different (not the graphs.nt) file and store extracted information in a new HashSet, created by another object.
In the rest of the code, I create a [Parser object](http://pastebin.com/R9RZQkn2), to which I pass a [Handler object](http://pastebin.com/VsJN6n0k).

This really confuses me. My guess is, that this somehow drives the JVM to allocate more memory for my program, which I can see hints for when I run top. Without the HashMap, it will allocate about 1 Gig of memory. If I initialize the HashMap, it will allocate > 2 Gigs.

My question is, if this sounds at all reasonable. Is it possible that creating such a big object will allocate more memory for the program to use afterwards? Shouldn't -Xmx and -Xms control the memory allocation or are there further arguments that maybe play a role here?

I am aware that this may seem like an odd question and that information is scarce, but this is all the information that I found related to the issue. If there is any more information that may be helpful, I am more than happy to provide it.

Comment: How were you doing it before this ? Adding a capacity would probably increase efficiency since the Map could distribute elements into buckets better.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. But maybe it was unclear: The HashMap that I create to "increase performance" is not the one that the actual application stores the data in! I basically add the above code to the beginning of the main-method and run the completely unrelated rest of the code afterwards.

Comment: I am asking what your code that actually does the work looks like.

Comment: Do you mean that none of the posted code is present in the lower-performing version? You are reading the file twice in the higher-performing version and just once in the lower-performing version?

Comment: Yes, but the file I read in the actual program is a different one. I am sorry I explained it badly. I hope I added some clarifying information.

Comment: I missed you had mentioned two different files in your original post; sorry about that. This is exceedingly weird. Have you tried profiling both cases to see where the time goes? There's also the possibility that the speed-up correlated with the extra I/O has something to do with the underlying environment rather than with Java. (By the way, what motivated you to try slapping this code at the front of your processing?)

Comment: I hadn't initially :) I can reproduce this behavior on my laptop and desktop, the laptop running Linux mint 15 and the desktop ubuntu server 13.04. I tried it with openjdk 6 and 7. I got to that because I do different processing tasks, almost all create some sort of lookup-table upfront. After hours of investigating why this particular processor was slower even though it does less, I ended up with this :)

Comment: You should monitor garbage collection with visualvm or, better, visualgc.

Comment: My guess is that the up-front processing causes the jit to kick in before your "real" code is run.  you could test whether the benefit is likely increased memory or jit by changing the up-front code to just be a few large memory allocations (instead of lots of processing _and_ lots of memory allocation).

Comment: @jtahlborn depending on the JVM, you could [disable JIT compilation entirely](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.user.zos.60%2Fuser%2Fdisjit.html) and see if the performance increase still occurs.

Comment: Would be interesting to try replacing the file access with a string generator -- just generate the strings "1", "2", "3"..., though perhaps with some extra text tacked on to make them about the same average length as with the file.

Comment: I replaced reading lines with a random alpha-numeric generator of 25 characters, so no more file reading. Performance is still increased. I also ran the 'pre-ignited' and 'non-pre-ignited' code with the -Xint switch, which forces interpreted mode. In this case there is no performance difference. Both versions then take about 65 seconds for a million lines. I guess this is a strong hint that it has something to do with the JIT ?

Answer (score 0):

Memory and GC can definitely impact performance. If possible you should run Xms==Xmx to disable resizing, and give JVM plenty of room at start. Your app could exit before any major GC is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you go out of your way to make it otherwise, "foo" will eventually pass out of scope and be collected, even if you don't nil the pointer, and even if the method containing the above code is never exited.  But it will have forced the heap to grow larger, and this will reduce the relative overhead of GC.

(It would be an interesting experiment to reference "foo" at the end of your program, to keep it in scope.)

Comment: You mean something like `System.out.println(foo.keySet().size());` ? I added that to the end, no drop in performance. It shouldn't pass out of scope anyway, because my main is basically the above code plus a `new Parser.parse()` line, kicking off the calculations.

Comment: @feob - Yeah, presumably that should do it.  So if that makes no difference then presumably it's because you "warmed up" HashMap.put in the JITC.  You could test that by replacing foo with some other unrelated (and unused in your "real" code) data structure.

Comment: (BTW, even dumb javac is probably smart enough to notice that foo isn't referenced and recycle the local var slot for it to some other use, allowing foo to pass out of scope if the following code is at all complex.)

Comment: Well, actually I use a HashSet later on in the code. But even if that wuld be the case, performance of the "uninitialized" code should catch up to the warmed up one eventually, shouldn't it? This is not the case in a program that runs ~30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like file caching? Your file "graphs.nt" is probably cached in RAM either by the OS or the JVM. GC will allow memory consumption to go up for performance reasons, if you add a forced collect right after your preload, `System.gc()`, you'll be able to tell if the caching happens in the JVM or in the OS.